# PHP loop not being applied on a specific HTML element

Tags: php, wordpress, while-loop

I have a PHP while loop as follow:

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<li> 
<?php
    $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'attachment',
      'numberposts' => -1,
      'post_status' => null,
      'post_parent' => $post->ID,
      'orderby' => 'menu_order',
      'order' => 'ASC'
    ); 

    $attachments = get_posts($args);

    if ($attachments) {
      foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
        $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment->ID, large );
        $alt_text_title = $attachment->post_title ;
        //print_r($attachment); 

        echo "<img src=\"$image_attributes[0]\" alt=\"$alt_text_title\">";
        }
    }
?>
<h3><a href="http://<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
<?php the_content(); ?>
</li>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

The a tag inside the h3 makes all the titles hyperlinks however I would like one of these title not be a link therefore not to be affected by the a tag at all..

Is this possible?

Comment: what is the the_title()? are you using some kind of framework?

Comment: wordpress for my portfoio... the_title() is picking up the title inserted for the related project.

Comment: Of course it's possible, almost all things are possible. unfortuanatly we can't tell you because we don't know what you know. If you know what the title is, and don't mind editing the while loop then put an if statement on the_title() but it's far from elegant. And you'll need to hope the title never changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit. A safer way it to do it via post ID.

```
<?php $postID = $post->ID;

echo $postID; 
// You could delete this line once you have the PostID. 

if($postID == '1') { ?>
  <h3><?the_title();?></h3>
<?php } else { ?>
  <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" title="<?php the_title();?>"><?the_title();?></a></h3>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: That would change ALL the H3 elements. He only wants to change one.

Comment: Edit to NOT output the `<a>` based on the PostID.

Answer (score 0):

You could always check the content of `the_title()` with an if and display the a tag only when necessary.

```
<?php if(the_title() === "your title") {?>
    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
<?php } else {?>
    <h3><a href="http://<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: the thing is that the content will always be inserted in the field so that condition will always be true..

Comment: Sorry, but then I don't really understand. Isn't there one specific title you don't want to display as a hyperlink? Couldn't you just replace "your title" with that specific title? A hardcoded string won't change no matter what. (Or are you trying to tell me that the_title() always contains the same string? Then of course it's something else ;))

Comment: The titles match the real hyperlinks, however one of them is not live for some reasons so I don't want that title to displayed with the a tag around.... Sorry if it's a bit confusing...

Answer (score 0):

```
$title=get_the_title();
if( /*post meets some condition*/) {
  ?><h3>$title</h3><?php
} else {
  ?><h3><a href="http://<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3><?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need a simple if statement. You can build the condition on any number of things in the example ill use the full title but it would probably be better to use the id of the post or something like that:

```
<?php if('Ignore this title' == get_the_title()): ?>
  <h3><?php the_title() ?></h3>
<?php else: ?>
  <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
<?php endif; ?>
```